# Z-index not working inside scroll-box

Tags: html, css

Hey guys have a look at my code , below is the HTML code ::

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="dialog">
        <div class="preScroll">
            <div class="header">header</div>
            <div class="scroller">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li><span>Label</span></li>
                        <li id="dropDown_open"><span>Click me!</span><div class="abs"></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">footer</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE HEER](http://jsfiddle.net/8p0jj2jk/4/)

CSS code here ::

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

#container .dialog {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    top: calc(50% - 150px);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: white;
}

#container .dialog .preScroll {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container .dialog .header,
#container .dialog .footer {
    height: 25px;
}

#container .dialog .scroller {
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

#container .dialog .scroller #dropDown_open {
    position: relative;
}

#container .dialog .scroller .abs {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 120%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#container .dialog .scroller #dropDown_open > span:hover ~ div.abs {
    display:block;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul li:last-child {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

see how I have added the following css to the .scroller class :

```
overflow: auto;
```

this causes content to be scrolled , how I have the following box inside one of the li's , like so `<div class="abs"></div>` , when you hover over , click me , this box will show , now , the box has the following styles :

```
#container .dialog .scroller .abs {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 120%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#container .dialog .scroller #dropDown_open > span:hover ~ div.abs {
    display:block;
}
```

now notice how .abs has a z-index:9999 , and inspite of this , it appears inside the `.scroller` div , **WHY SO** ? , I taught the .abs div will overlap and show outside the .scroller div . I want to know why its not doing so .

Please note that this is a WHY question , I want to know why my code does't work , not how to make it work , atleast not without knowing WHY .

Thank you.

Comment: because container has position relative

Comment: You need like http://jsfiddle.net/8p0jj2jk/32/ ?

Comment: @ketan , hehe no , I want it to overlap the entire scroll box !

Comment: this way using z-index you cannot not put child over parent

Answer (score 3):

Z-index depends on the parent container. So the z-index on your .abs has basically no effect. read: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/ for more info ;)

Here's how i imagine it:
Z-index values on elements are like sheets of papers. You can sort the childs of a element with z-index, but they cannot leave their parent element - they always stay between the two sheets, the parent lies.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index used for layers to which will be override other not for show div in other scop..

you have to write `<div class="abs"></div>` out of scroller.